# Giving MatrixPlot coordinates

Tags: matrix

I am using `MatrixPlot` for plotting the following array

```
{{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 
  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
  1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

By default matrixplot gives following image
[image]

where the coordinates are not complete. What I mean is in the $X$ axis, it starts from 1 and directly goes to 5 without printing 2,3,4. I want printing of 2,3,4 also. How to do that?

Comment: [`FrameTicks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html?q=FrameTicks)

Comment: FrameTicks -> All ? Does not work

Comment: @Nasser - Why did you delete your answer, which looks fine to me?